# Python: Applying arithmetic operators on list like on numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, numpy-ndarray

here's my first code, using numpy.linspace method:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def graph(formula, string, x1, x2):
    x = np.linspace(x1, x2)
    y = formula(string, x)
    plt.plot(x, y)


def my_formula(string, x):
    return eval(string)


graph(my_formula, "2 * (x ** 3) - 9.5 * (x ** 2) + 10.5 * x", 0, 3)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

it works fine, however, instead of importing numpy, if I do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Module:
    @staticmethod
    def linspace(finish, slices, start=0):
        each = float((finish - start) / (slices - 1))
        res = list()
        for i in range(slices):
            res.append(start + i * each)
        return res


def graph(formula, string, x1, x2):
    x = Module.linspace(x2, 50, start=x1)
    y = formula(string, x)
    plt.plot(x, y)


def my_formula(string, x):
    return eval(string)


graph(my_formula, "2 * (x ** 3) - 9.5 * (x ** 2) + 10.5 * x", 0, 3)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here's a error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/QINY/PycharmProjects/begin/covid/seven.py", line 24, in <module> graph(my_formula, "2 * (x ** 3) - 9.5 * (x ** 2) + 10.5 * x", 0, 3)
File "C:/Users/QINY/PycharmProjects/begin/covid/seven.py", line 16, in graph y = formula(string, x) File "C:/Users/QINY/PycharmProjects/begin/covid/seven.py", line 21, in my_formula return eval(string)
File "<string>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

Can anyone explain how it is done in numpy.adarray, to automatically iterate the list?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/QINY/PycharmProjects/begin/covid/seven.py", line 24, in <module>
    graph(my_formula, "2 * (x ** 3) - 9.5 * (x ** 2) + 10.5 * x", 0, 3)
  File "C:/Users/QINY/PycharmProjects/begin/covid/seven.py", line 16, in graph
    y = formula(string, x)
  File "C:/Users/QINY/PycharmProjects/begin/covid/seven.py", line 21, in my_formula
    return eval(string)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Ok, what exactly are you asking? What do you mean by "how is list iteration achieved"? This example is totally overcomplicated to ask about the problem I think you are asking.

Comment: you can use the nditer to iterate through array objects if the order in which the elements are iterated is not a concern to you: :https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use [Standard operators as functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__pow__).

Their type supports functions like `__pow__`, `__mul__`, `__add__`, etc... with implementations that apply the operations on each element of the `ndarray` (very efficiently...)

You can make your own type that inherits from `list` and have it implement these member functions, iterating the list yourself, applying it on every element.

Comment: `class Iteration:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

    def __pow__(self, power, modulo=None):
        new_array = list()
        for i in self.array:
            new_array.append(i ** power)
        return new_array

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.array)

    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        return self.array[indices]`

Comment: `it = Iteration([1, 2, 3])
def sub(list1, list2):
    new_list = list()
    for i, d in enumerate(list1):
        new_list.append(d - list2[i])
    return new_list

print(sub([6, 7, 8], it))   #=> [5, 5, 5]`